# Using AWS Batch to Update to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, batch-processing, aws-batch

Hi ,
    I am new to AWS and I have a use case where I have to process bulk updates on Amazon RDS DB based on the input files received in my S3 Bucket. Please validate my solution on this use case and correct me if I am wrong.

I will be using AWS Lambda function on arrival of file in S3 bucket to invoke AWS Batch processing which uses EC2 to do the processing and writes update to RDS.

```
S3 -> Lambda -> AWS Batch -> EC2 -> RDS
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a frequently-used pattern used by AWS Batch developers that should work well for you.